# Protractor typescript Error: WebDriverError: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect while selecting values from multi-select list

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumberjs

[image]I am trying to select options from multi select drop down ,it select few and then shows error WebDriverError: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect.

This is the function I am passing values from yml and one by one it check and clicks

```
async assignViewersToUser(viewsOption: string){
    if (viewsOption !== null) {
        browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        await this.viewersDropdown.click();
        var view = viewsOption.split(',');
        for (let i = 0; i < view.length; i++) {
            var viewsList = element.all(by.xpath('.//div[@class="pq-select-menu"]//span[contains(text(), "' + view[i] + '")]/parent::label/input'));
            await viewsList.filter(function (ele) {
                return ele.isDisplayed();
            }).then(async function (viewsList) {
                if (await viewsList[0].isSelected() === true) {
                    console.log(viewsList[0] + ' Case is Already selected');
                } else {
                    await viewsList[0].click();
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        console.log('No View found against this user');
    }
    await browser.sleep(1000);
}
```

Getting this exception

```
WebDriverError: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\ediscovery.ADLAB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\ediscovery.ADLAB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\ediscovery.ADLAB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)Error
    at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\ediscovery.ADLAB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:459:27)
    at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function).args [as isDisplayed] (C:\Users\ediscovery.ADLAB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:91:29)
    at ElementFinder.(anonymous function).args [as isDisplayed] (C:\Users\ediscovery.ADLAB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:831:22)
    at C:\Ihsan\QuinCTest\Test\Pages\UserPage.ts:353:20
    at parentWebElements.map (C:\Users\ediscovery.ADLAB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:229:28)
    at Array.map ((anonymous))
    at getWebElements.then (C:\Users\ediscovery.ADLAB\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:227:46)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some syntax issues with your function. When using async/await almost all actions need to be manually awaited now and `.then` are rarely required.

*Note: Just be aware that your function always selected the first checkbox only as `filteredList[0]` is hardcoded.*

Can you try the below approach and let me know?

```
async assignViewersToUser(viewsOption: string){

  //viewsOption should never be null so throw error if it it. Rest of function won't be executed if null
  if (viewsOption === null) throw new Error('viewsOption is null');

  //Need to await deleteAllCookies()
  await browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
  await this.viewersDropdown.click();

  var view = viewsOption.split(',');
  for (let i = 0; i < view.length; i++) {
    var viewsList = await element.all(by.xpath('.//div[@class="pq-select-menu"]//span[contains(text(), "' + view[i] + '")]/parent::label/input'));

    //No need to use .then when using awaits
    let filteredList = await viewsList.filter(function (ele) {
      return ele.isDisplayed();
    });

    if (await filteredList[0].isSelected() === true) {
      console.log(filteredList[0] + ' Case is Already selected');
    } else {
      await filteredList[0].click();
    }
  };

  await browser.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @DublinDev for correction it works but some time it shows this error. This is my observation that if list is too long then some time it happens. Can you tell me what are the possible reasons of  "WebDriverError: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect" error.

Comment: @IhsanRehman when you say 'list is too long' could you clarify what you mean? Are you referring to 10s of entries or 100s. By too long do you mean the list is off the screen and requires additional loading when you scroll or are all items loaded and available at initial load?

Comment: [This thread](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4706) may be of interest to you also